# Android layout design for different screen sizes

Tags: java, android, xml, androiddesignsupport

I am developing an android app but problem is, it's design doesn't remain consistent on different devices.

I studied about it on internet but finally I am stuck on the same problem.
I Created layout folders like layout-sw300dp, layout-sw320dp, layout-sw330dp, layout-sw360dp, layout-sw480dp, layout-sw600dp, layout-sw720dp, layout-sw800dp.
I create and design xml for each of this layout. In my Nexus S (4.3 inch) emulator it works perfectly as i designed but in my real device: Xiaomi Redmi 4 Prime (5 inch), it doesn't apply.
How can i fix this cause i stuck in it for about few days and counting.
Below i provided some images of emulator device and real device
[image]
[image]

Comment: What layout are you using?

Comment: Relative layout as root layout